# Using Netbeans + MySQL Database for login/register info, is this secure? If not, how would I secure this database from unauthorized access?

Tags: mysql, security, netbeans

I'm creating a multi-user chatroom for a school project. It must be secure.

I figure one of the ways I provide security is through a login system of some sort.

How would I create a secure database for the login information?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: I'm programming it using Java

Comment: Find a Java authentication framework, then, and use that. Access control is a solved problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Never heard of it - looking into it now

Comment: With security it's important to find existing solutions and adapt them to your needs. This is like if you want to lock your front door the last thing you should do is make your own lock.